# border radius being overriden? Image rendering as rectangle

Tags: flutter

I am trying to render images with curved edges, however, the images are still rendering as a plain rectangle.

Am I overriding the `borderradius` at all? Any thoughts on how to rectify?

```
GridView.count(
                              shrinkWrap: true,
                              crossAxisCount: 2,
                              childAspectRatio: (50 / 80),
                              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(3.0),
                              children:
                                  List.generate(widget.imageArray.length, (index) {
                                return Container(
                                    child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index],
                                        fit: BoxFit.fill),
                                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      color: Colors.grey[800],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)
```

Comment: set the clip in container to resolve the issue. Container(clip: Clip.antiAlias)

Comment: @BalasubramaniSundaram I had tried that as well. Unless I am just doing wrong... Can you provide an answer?

Comment: @BalasubramaniSundaram Your edit still does not seem to work...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `ClipRRect`

```
      ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Image.file(widget.imageArray[index], fit: BoxFit.fill),
      ),
```